# Alfresco Share: different due date in each usertask

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

In out-of-the-box activiti adhoc workflow, how can I change due date for every usertask?

Comment: For all open tasks for all users, or for just one user? And are you happy to do it with Java, or does it need to be in JS?

Answer (score 2):

if you  should use `bpm:dueDate` or `bpm:workflowDueDate`property depending on your requirement...